# How to close WPF windows?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm creating several WPF windows like this:

```
flightWindow = new FlightWindow(txbNextFlight.Text, airline);
flightWindow.Show();
```

And when I click on a button inside this windows I want the window to close. Not sure how to solve this?

Comment: Probably because the title makes absolutely no sense, and the question isn't much better.

Comment: I missed the word "close" in the title!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class FlightWindow : Window
    {
        public FlightWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```